# Specialized template accepting constructor parameter when only default constructor defined

Tags: c++11

So, I have this template class and its specialization.

```
    #include <iostream>

    using namespace std;

    template<bool> struct CompileTimeChecker{

         CompileTimeChecker(...); //constructor, can accept any number of parameters;

    };

    //specialized template definition

    template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {

        //default constructor, body empty

    };
```

**Case 1:**

In the `main` function I am defining a local class called `ErrorA`. When I create a temporary of  `CompileTimeChecker<false>` with temporary object of `ErrorA` fed as an initializer, the compiler is not detecting any error.

```
int main()
{

    class ErrorA {};

    CompileTimeChecker<false>(ErrorA()); //Case 1;

    CompileTimeChecker<false>(int());    //Case 2;

    return 0;

}
```

**Case 2:**

Next I feed it with temporary object of type `int`, and suddenly the compiler recognizes the issue (there is no constructor that takes args in the specialized template `CompileTimeChecker<false>`)

```
main.cpp:30:36: error: no matching function for call to ‘CompileTimeChecker::CompileTimeChecker(int)’ CompileTimeChecker<false>(int());

main.cpp:21:23: note: candidate: constexpr CompileTimeChecker::CompileTimeChecker()
     template<> struct CompileTimeChecker<false> {
                       ^~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
main.cpp:21:23: note:   candidate expects 0 arguments, 1 provided
```

**Why does it not recognize the issue in case 1?**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
CompileTimeChecker<false>(ErrorA());
```

does not create a temporary of type `CompileTimeChecker<false>`, passing a temporary `ErrorA()` to its constructor. Rather, it declares a function named `ErrorA`, taking no parameters and returning `CompileTimeChecker<false>` . See also: [most vexing parse](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Most_vexing_parse).

On the other hand, `CompileTimeChecker<false>(int());` cannot be parsed as a declaration, so it does unambiguously create a temporary of type `CompileTimeChecker<false>`.

The easiest way out is to use braces in place of parens to indicate initialization:

```
CompileTimeChecker<false>{ErrorA{}};
```

Comment: Consistent with this answer, I slightly modify "case 1" to be less *ambiguous*, and get error.  http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/26e9cfaf94d212e3    ;  Good question and nice answer, by the way.

Comment: @javaLover Just simply `CompileTimeChecker<false>{ErrorA{}};` would work. Uniform initialization in C++11 is designed to avoid most vexing parse, among other things.

Comment: Good explanation and reference! Adding on, will double parenthesis suffice in cases like this (as suggested by the reference linked) @javaLover?

Comment: @User10482 I am not sure what you mean, but Igor's solution `{ErrorA{}}` should work and beautiful.

Comment: ```{class ERROR; (void)sizeof(CompilerTimeChecker<(expr) !=0>((ERROR())));}``` This is an excerpt from Modern C++ Designing book by Andrei. I am inclined to think that the superfluous parenthesis for ```ERROR()``` serves the purpose of preventing the ambiguity. @javaLover @IgorTandetnik

Comment: @User10482 Yes, I think the extra parens were used to work around most vexing parse. This book likely pre-dates C++11. Since C++11, there's no need to hand-roll `CompilerTimeChecker` in the first place - it's built into the language under the name [`static_assert`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/static_assert)

Comment: @User10482  I've never heard of such technique. I started to learn C++ after it was C++11.  Thank for the knowledge.

Comment: IgorTandetnik @javaLover Appreciate all the help!